# Property binding combined with hardcoded text via Controller

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to bind some data retrieved from my dataset together with a hardcoded text.

I know that I could solve this requirement by binding my dataset and hardcoded text in the view like this:

```
<Text id="textPropertyBinding-id" text="{/BusinessPartnerSet('0100000002')/WebAddress} - Success"/>
```

but I was wondering if I could realize the same via the controller.

```
<Text id="textPropertyBinding-id" text=""/>
```

```
this.getView().byId("textPropertyBinding-id").bindText({
    parts: [
        {
            path: "/BusinessPartnerSet('0100000002')" + "/WebAddress"
        },
            // here I want to add hardcoded text: ' - Success'

    ]
});
```

I've searched for what  properties I can add to the binding-object but can't seem to find much info.
I've tried with property `text`, `value` but those properties weren't allowed.

The expected result would be:

'webaddress - Success'

Any advices from the experts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the version you are on, you could either use a formatter function like this

```
this.byId("textPropertyBinding-id").bindText({
    path: "/BusinessPartnerSet('0100000002')/WebAddress",
    formatter: function (sText) {
        return sText + "- Success";
    }
});
```

As of 1.61 you can also define a hardcoded text with the new value parameter

```
this.byId("textPropertyBinding-id").bindText({
    parts: [{
        path: "/BusinessPartnerSet('0100000002')/WebAddress"
    }, {
        value: "- Success"
    }]
});
```

PS: You don't have to call getView() first, you can directly use byId() from the controller of the view.